# constructing the optimal polynomial approximation of a continuous function

Tags: approximation-theory

By the Weierstrass theorem, we know that on an interval $[a,b]$, any continuous function $f(x)$ can be approximated to arbitrary precision by polynomials. In terms of the $L_\infty$ norm, it means that the set of polynomials is dense in the space of continuous functions $C[a,b]$.

The question is, for given continuous function $f$, suppose we want a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree no higher than $N$ so as to minimize the distance between $f$ and $P$,

$$ dist(f, P ) =  max_{a\leq x\leq b} |f(x) -P(x) | . $$

How to find this polynomial? **The difficulty is that we have not a Hilbert space.**

Comment: Let $x_{m,n} = \frac{b\;m + a(n-m)}{n}$ .  Let $S_{n} = \{x_{k,n} | k\in \{0,1,\dots n \}\}$.

Solve  $P$ for $dist_n(f, P ) =  max_{x \in S_{n} } |f(x) -P(x) |$ (this should be a simple set of $m$ linear inequalities in $N$ unknowns) . As we increase the size of $n$ this should converge to our ideal solution.

Comment: @user3257842 Unfortunately this can diverge. Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon

Comment: Generally polynomial minimax approximations have to be found numerically, and the main workhorse of this is the [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm). Given the numerical nature of the algorithm, it will find *near minimax* approximations.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni  The divergence only occurs when when there is no upper bound to the maximum degree of our polynomials. The post already said the maximum degree $N$ is fixed from the start. In this case the solution can be represented as a vector $\mathbb{R}^N$, and the computations should converge, not diverge, as the number of equidistant points increases.  I believe the concrete cases of $m$ equidistant points for a given $m$ can be solved with linear programing.

Comment: But, having looked it over, the Remez algorithm. does indeed seem like the best choice for solving the problem.